# Populate Listbox using ADO Recordset

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ado, recordset

Below is my Code for POpulating ListBox using ADO Recordset . It is working but not in a way it should be display in form.[image]

```
   Function PopulatelstReview()
    Dim sList As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ADORs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSearchResult As String
    Set AdoCn = New ADODB.Connection

    Set AdoCmd = New ADODB.Command

    AdoCn.Open AdoConnectionString

    AdoCmd.ActiveConnection = AdoConnectionString
    Debug.Print AdoConnectionString

    Set ADORs = New ADODB.Recordset
    'rs.Open "TestListReview", AdoCn
    ADORs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    'rs.Open strSQL, AdoConnectionString, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText


        AdoCmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        AdoCmd.CommandText = "TestListReview"
       Set rs = AdoCmd.Execute
    Set ADORs = ExecuteStoredProcedure("TestListReview", AdoCmd)

    With ADORs
    lstReview.RowSourceType = "Value List"
          lstReview.ColumnHeads = False

              Label43.Caption = ADORs.Fields(0).Name
         Label44.Caption = ADORs.Fields(1).Name
           Label45.Caption = ADORs.Fields(2).Name
            Label48.Caption = ADORs.Fields(3).Name
             Label49.Caption = ADORs.Fields(4).Name
              Label50.Caption = ADORs.Fields(5).Name
               Label51.Caption = ADORs.Fields(6).Name
               Label52.Caption = ADORs.Fields(7).Name

                lstReview.AddItem ADORs!id
                lstReview.AddItem ADORs!TradePartner
                lstReview.AddItem ADORs!TrustAccount
                lstReview.AddItem ADORs!Date
                lstReview.AddItem ADORs!CurrentBalance
                lstReview.AddItem ADORs!FileName
                lstReview.AddItem ADORs!RecordNum
                lstReview.AddItem ADORs!ImportDateTime

                 sList = ADORs.GetString(adClipString, , ";", ";")
            'lstReview.RowSourceType = "Value List"
            'lstReview.RowSource = sList
      End With
    'Call RS2WS(ADORs, "A3")
    'lstReview.Column(0, 1) = "ID"

    End Function
```

I need that each value should come under appropiate columns which i placed in labels.please tell me how can i do this

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Excel or Access?
if you are using Access you could import/linked table and use normal queries as (recordsource) to populate list boxes.

anyhow, here is a pseudo code to populate a listbox using your method. After you have connected to the server and executed your SQL statement try following codes.

```
Dim RC, CC As Long
ADORs.MoveLast ' vba will not know the total row until you scroll down to the last
RC = ADORs.RecordCount ' get the result row count
CC = ADORs.Fields.count ' get the field/column count
ADORs.MoveFirst ' Move back to the first record

lstReview.ColumnHeads = True
lstReview.ColumnCount = CC ' Number of column as in the recordset

'Fill the column names
Dim I As Integer
For I = 0 To CC - 1
    lstReview.Column(I, 0).value = ADORs.Fields(I).name
Next I


'Fill the data
Dim J As Integer
While Not ADORs.EOF
    For I = 1 To RC - 1
        For J = 0 To CC - 1
            lstReview.Column(J, I).value = ADORs.Fields(J).value
        Next J
    Next I
    ADORs.MoveNext 'moving to next record
Wend
```

Also you should consider trapping errors such as if the SQL execution has returned any records.

for access you can use this

```
If Nz(ADORs.RecordCount, 0) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Sorry no records found.."
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

if you are using excel you can use something like this

```
If isNull(ADORs.RecordCount) or (ADORs.RecordCount = 0) Then
    MsgBox "Sorry no records found.."
    Exit Sub
End If
```

hope this helps.. enjoy :)

Comment: hey thanks for your response but unfortunately i'm stil getting errors on ADORs.MoveLast line as "Rowset doesnot support fetching backwards." and on lstReview.Column(I, 0).value = ADORs.Fields(I).Name line as "Run Time Error:424 Object Required"... please tell me if u have any idea about these errors.

Comment: thats because of your connection to the server is incompatible/wrong type? You still haven't answered the first question, are you using excel or Access?
what is your connectionstring?
see this comment for adodb connection: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524210/execute-sql-query-from-excel/25528990#25528990

Comment: thanks for ur valuable time ...i have used connection string as "Provider = sqloledb;" & _"Data Source=" & ServerString & ";" & _"Initial Catalog=" & DatabaseString & ";" & _"User ID=" & UserIdString & ";" & _"Password=" & PwdString & ";""" ; i have declared those variables as Global. i am using Access working on vba.

Comment: if you are using ACcess, why don't you import the tables from your SQL database as linked tables? also try to use plain connectionstring first before constructing from variables :)
have a look in http://www.connectionstrings.com/  for connectionstrings

Comment: There is no `.value` after `.Column(colIndex, rowIndex)`, it is just: `.Column(col, row) = rec.Fields(col).Value`